# Unable to run fastboot commands: < waiting for device >

Tags: adb, fastboot

I want to unlock my Nexus 5. I cannot run any fastboot command however: the device is not detected. What I did:

1. Press VolumeDown+rightButton until arriving to this screen

[image]

2. Plug the phone
3. Run the following commands

though I appear to be in fastboot mode

```
# apt-get install fastboot
# fastboot oem unlock
< waiting for device >
```

Nothing is disaplaye after the last line.

PS: I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: If that's your device in the screenshot (rather than an image taken from elsewhere) then it looks like it's already unlocked. That could explain why it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @bmdixon It should, no matter it is unlocked or locked. otherwise how do you do if you want to relock it?

Comment: This is 6 months late, but adding `sudo` to the fastboot cammands solved the problem for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably don't have USB drivers installed. Download them and install, everything should work now.

1. Download them from [here](https://dl-ssl.google.com//android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip)
2. Download Galaxy Nexus drivers [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/verizon-wireless/SCH-I515MSAVZW)

   - Power on the device
   - Go to Settings > Developers Options > USB Debugging then enable it.
   - Connect the device to the computer, drivers should be installed
   - Open a terminal and check if the phone is detected: *`adb devices`* (Windows)
   - You should get some `hex numbers` as output
   - Then reboot to the bootloader: `adb reboot-bootloader`
   - Then check if the device is detected in Fastboot: `fastboot devices`
   - Finally proceed with the Unlocking process: `fastboot oem unlock` or `fastboot flash unlock` if the previous doesn't work.

PS: *Seems like you use a Linux system, I'm not familiar with Linux. You should use Linux commands.*

Comment: You write "You probably don't have USB drivers installed" <--  I have an OPPO A9(maybe same as OPPO A5) phone, I think it can't get to a boot loader.. I understand that maybe fastboot commands require that one is in the bootloader.  I can do adb devices, so I think my USB  related adb drivers are fine.

Comment: Did you try booting into the bootloader with ADB?

Comment: It's an OOPPO A9 2020..  When I do adb reboot bootloader it just restarts the phone into the system, it doesn't go to the bootloader.  If I do power-voldown, and start it then it  still doesn't go to the bootloader, it goes to a recovery called ColorOS

Comment: Well, if I'm not wrong, you need to Volume up + Power to enter bootloader mode. Did you try it already?

Comment: Oh and there should be a parameter that you need to enable, located in the Developpers Options settings: Check if OEM Unlocking is present and enabled.

Comment: @es oh that OEM unlocking option is done... that is required for adb devices to work, so that adb devices doesn't show "unauthorized device".  I did that. adb devices is fine. So that's not it.  it's fastboot commands that won't work. And adb reboot bootloader that isn't working.

Comment: Nope, OEM Unlock is for the bootloader unlocking. To unable ADB you just need to enable USB Debugging. I'm afraid your device might not have been shipped with the ability to access the bootloader, many chinese devices are built that way

Comment: thanks, I see from .. https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-fix-adb-devices-shows-unauthorized-device     the unauthorized is because you need to pick  "Revoke USB debugging authorizations".  I suppose  that gets rid of the "unauthorized" message from adb devices .  Still anyhow, yeah chinese device, can't access bootloader!