# How can I root my Lenovo Tab 4 10 (TB—X304L)?

Tags: rooting, bootloader-lock, lenovo

I've been trying to root my Lenovo Tablet for past few weeks and I've got no success.

I found out an [article](https://forum.xda-developers.com/thinkpad-tablet/general/twrp-root-tab-4-plus-tb-x704l-f-tb-t3664407) in XDA showing how to root it but when I tried I got stuck in the third step which was unlocking the bootloader.

When I typed `fastboot oem unlock-go` in my laptop and hit enter the adb and fastboot software just kept displaying *"waiting for device"* and nothing happened.

I have been searching whole internet to find a reliable tutorial because I am a newbie in this rooting thing.

Even One Click Root doesn't have any solution.

And I don't want to have any spywares in my device therefore I don't want to root it through any one click root services (like One click root, King Root, etc)

I apologize if I am missing something.

*Any help would be highly appreciated.*

Edit:— It seems like the OP of [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/164569/316950) post faced the same problem. Can anyone tell me how to use the `sudo` code?

I will try to install the drivers (as pointed out by an answer) and then edit here.

Comment: Does `fastboot devices` show device information?

Comment: It does show the device name when I enter fastboot and connect my tab.

Comment: Since you say are new to rooting, double checking - OEM unlock and USB debug in developer options done?

Comment: Yes, I did click on both of them.

Comment: Apart from changing USB slots, and connecting cable, I can't think of anything. Let others contribute // If you are using windows I hope adb is run as admin or system wide

Comment: Hey what is a sudo code in fastboot?

Comment: That's a different issue. Please wait for other knowledgeable people to help

Comment: `fastboot oem get_unlock_data` https://support.motorola.com/us/en/bootloader

Comment: 'sudo' is a linux command line prefix for running cmd with root privileges - like running cmd as administrator on windows

Comment: I've finally unlocked my bootloader. I tried the sudo command and then usual fastboot oem unlock command and it worked.